# how can i resolve a 404 in my ionic page?

Tags: python, angular, ionic-framework, routes, http-status-code-404

I am working on a project where I have to program a mobile application page using Ionic in Angular. While I am facing other issues, the one I am most interested in solving is the typical 404 error 'page not found.' I have created an HTML page for that error in my project, but it doesn't appear even when I run the application. How can I solve this?

I have searched for answers through ChatGPT. It tells me that I should make sure to import IonicModule from @ionic/angular, as well as IonHeader and IonToolbar from @ionic/angular in my e404.page.ts file. I have also imported Error404Page from :/error404/error404.page hoping that it would fix the issue, but I still can't resolve it.

Comment: Can you show your routes ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.